# Show bootstrap alert when have content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display bootstrap alert when it have content

It get content only when I do a push, but if it doesn't have content I want to see it like

[image]

**Code:**

```
 <div class="alert alert-success">
                <ul id="discussion"></ul>
            </div>
```

how can I hide it if  `<ul id="discussion"></ul>` is empty? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use the below javascript at the bottom of page:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var doc = document.getElementById('discussion').textContent;
  if(doc == '')
     document.getElementById('discussion').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: @Ledwing have you added this script at the bottom of page.

Comment: Yes with script tags and I add debugger and I dont get errors

Comment: it hide it now but when it get content from push  it dont showed up

Comment: I try as `else {
                document.getElementById('discussion').show();` but it always showig up